# Extract all the named parameters from a given url in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 1 doubt regarding this...

i have a url like this

http://www.SpiderWeb.com/vendors/search_results/scid:0/atr:1/mbp:1/bc:2/bc:1/mbpo:2/atrt:5/atop:1/opel:4

I want to extract all the named parameters in an array vars such that I have the name of the variable as well it's value in the url so that I can use them for some processing...

Is there some way by which i can achieve this uisng some build-in functions rather than assiging them individually

i.e

```
$some_var = $this->request->params['named']['id'];
```

The resaon i want it is because the named parameters are dynamic ....

heres the updated solution for this...

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.SpiderWeb.com/vendors/search_results/scid:0/atr:1/mbp:1/bc:2/bct:1/mbpo:2/atrt:5/atop:1/opel:4';
$arr_url = parse_url($url);
//print_r($arr_url);
$res  = explode("/vendors/search_results/",$arr_url['path']);
//print_r($res);
//print_r($res[1]);
$vars  = explode("/",$res[1]);
//print_r($vars);
$result = array();
foreach($vars as $key => $val){
  if (strpos($val, ":") !== false) {
     $newvars  = explode(":",$val);
     //print_r($newvars);
     $result[$newvars[0]] = $newvars[1];
  }
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry guys forgot to mention that the url is retrieved from the databse and the ouput should look like Array
(
    [scid] => 0
    [atr] => 1
    [mbp] => 1
    [bc] => 2
    [bc] => 1
    [mbpo] => 2
    [atrt] => 5
    [atop] => 1
    [opel] => 4
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$url = 'http://www.SpiderWeb.com/vendors/search_results/scid:0/atr:1/mbp:1/bc:2/bc:1/mbpo:2/atrt:5/atop:1/opel:4';

$myarr = parse_url($url);


$res  = explode("/",$myarr['path']);

foreach($res as $val){
  if (strpos($val, ":") !== false) {
     $vars  = explode(":",$val);
     $$vars[0]  = $vars[1];
  }
}

echo $scid;
```

Comment: Edited the anser please check it

Comment: Thankyou for this code snippet, i have to make some modifications to get the desired result and now it works great...
Once again thanku very much...I have also updated your code accordingly....

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the named params array

```
foreach ($this->request->params['named'] as $name => $param) {
   pr("The param name is {$name}");
   pr("The param value is {$param}");
}
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that the url i have is actually retrieved from the database. so i think i cannot get the values in $this->request->params['named']....